render PDF file from backend to front end using react-pdf
I want to render a pdf that is stored in the backend nodejs public folder and show it in the front end reactjs , and here is my code:
front end
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Document, Page,pdfjs } from "react-pdf";

import PdfComp from './pdfComp';
import axiosClient from "../axiosConfig"

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
    "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js",
    import.meta.url
  ).toString();
  pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.min.js`;

function MyPDFViewer() {
  const [pdfDoc, setPdfDoc] = useState(null);

const[pdfBlob,setPdfBlob]=useState(null)


    const fetchFile =  () => {
        
         axiosClient.post("/wp/getPdf",{data:"Mohamed.pdf"}, {responseType: 'blob' })
      
          .then(result=>setPdfBlob(result.data))
        
     
    }
   


  
    useEffect(() => {
      const loadPDF = async () => {
        if (pdfBlob) {
          const doc = await Document.load(pdfBlob);
          setPdfDoc(doc);
        }
      };
  
      loadPDF();
    }, [pdfBlob]);
   

  

  return (

    <div>
        <div>test</div>
        <button onClick={fetchFile}>Show</button>
    <div>
    {pdfDoc && (
      <Document file={pdfDoc}>
        {Array.from({ length: pdfDoc.numPages }, (_, i) => (
          <Page key={`page_${i + 1}`} pageNumber={i + 1} />
        ))}
      </Document>
    )}
  </div>

  
  </div>
  );
}

export default MyPDFViewer;


and here is the backend
const getPdf=async(req:Request,res:Response)=>{
    try{
        console.log(req.body.data)
        const filePath =  'public/Mohamed.pdf'; // Adjust path
        res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"..","..",filePath))
    
        
    
     }catch(err){
        throw new Error (`error at handler update intitator ${err}`)
    }
    
}



const WPRouter=(app:Application)=>{
    app.post ('/wp/getPdf',getPdf)
}

 
export default WPRouter;

But I got the following error
TypeError: react_pdf__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.load is not a function
Do you have any advice to over come this error .
have you any other suggestion to show this pdf on the reactjs while it is still stored on backend folder public one.
